# R: Use gsub to capture no match backreference

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to do something using `regex` and back references which involves grabbing the strings that do not have functions within them and placing them within the `f(x)` function.

```
a <- c("x(1)","y(212)", "z(b)","234", "cd")

gsub("solution", "f\\(\\1\\)", a)
# "x(1)"   "y(212)" "z(b)"   "f(234)"    "f(cd)" 

# Naively I have tried the following:
gsub("(.*)&[^(*.\\(.*\\))]", "f\\(\\1\\)", a)
gsub("(.*)&[!(*.\\(.*\\))]", "f\\(\\1\\)", a)
gsub("(.*)&(!(*.\\(.*\\)))", "f\\(\\1\\)", a)
```

Comment: Is this what you want? `gsub("^([^)])+$", "f(\\1)", a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match and capture strings that don't contain parenthesis and then wrap it with `f()`; For strings that do have parenthesis in them, since they don't match the pattern, they will stay as they are:

```
sub("^([^()]+)$", "f(\\1)", a)
# [1] "x(1)"   "y(212)" "z(b)"   "f(234)" "f(cd)"
```